# Low-budget film with an amnesiac woman on a spaceship turning evil

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

Can anyone help me find the title of an indie sci fi film? My guess is that the film is probably somewhere between 2007-12.
It is a lower budget film that is a mix of Pandorum, Doom or Resident Evil.

Plot:
A woman awakens in a spaceship med lab alone and with no memory.
A group of soldiers are going to the lower levels of the ship to kill mutants or infected that have turned into monsters/mutants.
Most of the soldiers are killed off.
The woman with no memory groups with some doctors who have survived and one or two of the surviving soldiers.
One by one they all get infected or die as the woman with no memory and the one soldier fight their way out of the ship.
The entire time the woman is turning into some sort of evil being on the inside. She looks fine but at the final moment she kills the soldier who was escorting her and alone makes her way to safety.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't talking about Resident evil. The plot you've described is pretty much identical.

Comment: sounds cool... i'd like to see it =]

Comment: The plot is clearly a mash up up Resident Evil,Pandorum and Doom... It was a much lower budget film than Resident Evil and more or less independent possibly Australian...Its been in the back of my mind and the tip of my tongue for weeks but have been unable to figure it out...

Answer (score 3):

After a month or so I found the name to this film.

It is [The Dark Lurking](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1391579/) (2009) which I believe has the alternative title of "***Aliens vs Zombies***" and "***Alien Undead***". Quite why the other titles were added, I'm not sure.

I was correct in the fact it was a low budget ($1,000,000) Australian horror/scifi film..